# Maps don't show up on android phone

Tags: android, html, google-maps

Our company has 2 maps on our contact page which show up fine in a browser but when we tried them on an android phone there is a just blank space where the map should be.
http://www.evercam.com/contact
Anyone have any idea why they don't show up?
Here is some code for the maps:

```
<div class="address">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h4>Dublin</h4>
          <p>The Ierne Ballroom, 12 Parnell Square East, Dublin 1, <br/>Ireland</p>
          <p>Telephone:  +353 (1) 538 3333</p>
          <p>E-Mail: <a href="mailto:info@evercam.io">howrya@evercam.io</a></p>
          <div class="map"><iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?mid=zo2fMMAkgMMs.kuabCDr3nlic" width="640" height="480"></iframe></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h4>Mountain View, California</h4>
          <p>800 W. El Camino Real, Suite 350, Mountain View,<br/> CA 94040, USA</p>
          <p>Telephone:  +1 (650) 419 3588</p>
          <p>E-Mail: <a href="mailto:info@evercam.io">whassup@evercam.io</a></p>
          <div class="map"><iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?mid=zo2fMMAkgMMs.kzJ0biOyIYMo" width="640" height="480"></iframe></div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end address -->
```

Comment: Just tested it on my HTC One running chrome and after a geolocation warning they load fine, what browser are you using?

Comment: doesn't work on my HTC One S with chrome

Comment: Works on HTC's default 'internet' browser with mine too but took a long time to load, 10-12 seconds after the rest of the page was rendered and that's on 4G in the UK.

Comment: I'm using chrome on a nexus 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's due to you using maps engine. when I go to the link you provided, it asks me to sign in as my Google account. When I deny it doesn't load the maps. When I accepted, it gives me a message about using my location but DOES show the maps. (Chrome - Nexus 5).

Maybe it's a privacy setting somewhere that you need a Google account to sign in? It's unusual because I followed the maps link in Incognito mode and also in IE where I'm not signed in.

Also Google says to just copy the HTML address from the maps window when embedding maps. Maybe if you just added the address straight from maps.google.com?

Link to Google support about embedding maps: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/72644?hl=en (to be honest it's not very helpful).

EDIT:
I don't think its a location issue seeing as how I'm only 850 metres away from ye :D

Comment: My browsers do log in automatically so perhaps that is something to do with it (i wasn't given a sign in notification), though like you I tried in incognito and it still works. Very odd.

Comment: Yeah, just tried incognito mode in Chrome on phone and it works no problem. Odd indeed!

Comment: I just found the same thing. We were using a new version of google maps that you can see in the image on Swire's answer below. We are going to switch back to the old google maps now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot]

Wanted to post this as a comment but can't include an image. I have tested on chrome on my HTC One and gen2 Nexus 7, plus HTC's 'internet' browser and the maps are loading. Slowly, but they're loading.

Is this a locational issue perhaps? I'm in the UK if that makes a difference.

This: https://support.google.com/mapsenginelite/answer/3024939?hl=en&ref_topic=3024936 seems to indicate that mobile browsers are not fully supported, in fact they don't appear in the supported browser list here either: https://support.google.com/mapsenginelite/answer/3034273?hl=en&ref_topic=3024936

Comment: I don't think so, we are based in Ireland. I reckon we might have to use the API key with google maps?

Comment: You shouldn't for the free version, plus if it were a requirement then I can't see why it would be working on some devices.

Comment: Yea thats true. We might try that anyway though unless we find a solution